# MySQL Using UNION or OUTER LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with what seems a simple enough query.
I have three tables, Accounts, Contacts & Activities.
Everytime an Activity is logged it logs the AccountID, Contact Subject, TimeDate.

I query the Activities table to show me all the activity count from the previous week for each AccountID.

I use:

```
select
accounts.account as Account,
count(distinct activities.contactid) as Users,
from accounts, activities
where activities.accountid=accounts.accountid
AND completeddate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND completeddate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
group by accounts.account asc;
```

The result is something like This:

```
Account      Users
ACME Ltd     4
Warner Bros  6
RBS          9
```

etc..

The activities table has baout 20 million rows and this runs in about 20 seconds.

However, I want a comprehensive list.
I want to combine the results with a list of AccountID's that havent had any activity for that month.

```
Account      Users
ACME Ltd     4
Warner Bros  6
RBS          9
Microsoft    0  or NULL
```

etc...

i have tried to UNION like this:

```
select Account, '' from Accounts
UNION
select
accounts.account as Account,
count(distinct activities.contactid) as Users
from accounts, activities
where activities.accountid=accounts.accountid
AND completeddate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND completeddate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
group by accounts.account asc;
```

From what i understand about UNION is that it should return a unique list (without duplicates).  But what i get is a list of aprox 1400 accounts with when I only have approx 900 Accounts.

I have tried LEFT OUTER JOIN but this just seemed to run forever ( i killed it after 2 hours)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this the `left outer join` that you tried?

```
select accounts.account as Account,
       count(distinct activities.contactid) as Users
from accounts left outer join
     activities
     on activities.accountid=accounts.accountid
where completeddate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY and
      completeddate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
group by accounts.account asc;
```

This should have about the same performance as your original query.

By the way, you should always use the explicit `join` syntax (`join` keyword in the `from` clause), rather than an implicit join in the `where` clause.

It seems that `completeddate` is in the activities table (always use aliases).  This needs to be moved into the `on` clause in that case:

```
select accounts.account as Account,
       count(distinct activities.contactid) as Users
from accounts left outer join
     activities
     on activities.accountid=accounts.accountid and
        activities.completeddate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY and
        activities.completeddate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
group by accounts.account asc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, thats what i tried, but it just gives me the same results as:  select 
accounts.account as Account, 
count(distinct activities.contactid) as Users
from accounts, activities 
where activities.accountid=accounts.accountid 
AND completeddate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND completeddate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
group by accounts.account asc;

Comment: @user2054962 . . . You should always uses aliases for your columns.  The column `completeddate` is in the `activities` table (presumably) and that turns the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.  The solution is to move the logic into the `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just testing it now, i didnt even know you cold use it like that! will let you know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: 12 minutes and counting, considering the orignal query took around 20 seconds, would the left outer join increase the query time vastly?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to combine the selects with "or" or "and" - logic.

For "or" use `UNION DISTINCT` for "and" use `INNER JOIN` on the primary key.

Comment: I tried UNION DISTINCT but for some reason it gives me 1495 rows when i only have 900 Accounts.  THis is whats baffling me. Thanks

Comment: It will work if you select only the account id, otherwise it will think the results are different because the other columns are different.

Comment: but then I loose the "count" which is the overall aim of the query.

Comment: Okay, if you want counts from both selects then actually it is correct that you get 1495 rows because an account may satisfy both conditions. Add a colum that has zero or one in it to indicate where the count comes from and you are set up and can read both counts in one go. You can add the counts in PHP.